# how I can show current user location in Google Map only once, when I open the fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

how I can show current user location in Google Map only once, when I open the fragment in Android Studio?
I use this code, but camera constant move to the user current location. When the user moves the map, it automatically moves back to the current location.

```
public class MapsFragment extends Fragment implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener, OnMapReadyCallback {

private SharedPreferences sharedPref;

private GoogleMap gMap;

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

private Location locationData;


private static final long TIME_INTERVAL_GET_LOCATION = 1000 * 5; 
private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 5000;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, null);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        TedPermission.with(getActivity())
        .setPermissionListener(permissionlistener)
        .setDeniedMessage("If you reject permission,you can not use this service\n\nPlease turn on permissions at [Setting] > [Permission]")
        .setPermissions(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        .check();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .build();

        return rootView;
        }


@Override
public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();


        }

        PermissionListener permissionlistener = new PermissionListener() {
@Override
public void onPermissionGranted() {

        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
        .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
        .setInterval(TIME_INTERVAL_GET_LOCATION)    
        .setFastestInterval(TIME_INTERVAL_GET_LOCATION); 


        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        locationChecker(mGoogleApiClient, getActivity());
        }
        }

@Override
public void onPermissionDenied(ArrayList<String> deniedPermissions) {
        }
        };

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
        }
  

        FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity());
        mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, new LocationCallback() {
@Override
public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
        locationData = locationResult.getLastLocation();
        if (locationData != null) {

        LatLng myLocation = new LatLng(locationData.getLatitude(), locationData.getLongitude());

        gMap.clear();

        gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myLocation).title("You are here!").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(myLocation).zoom(14).build();
        gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
   

        }

        }
        }, null);

        }

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

        }

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

       //........
        

        }

public void locationChecker(GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient, final Activity activity) {
        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
        .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
        LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());
        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
@Override
public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
final Status status = result.getStatus();
final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
        switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
        
        break;
        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
       
        try {
       
        status.startResolutionForResult(activity, 1000);

        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
        
        }
        break;
        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
       
        break;
        }
        }

            });
        }

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    {


        }
        }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        gMap = googleMap;
        gMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
        gMap.setBuildingsEnabled(false);
        gMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        gMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        gMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        gMap.setIndoorEnabled(false);
        gMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);



          
        }


}
```

What I should to do to fix that? How i can turn off the map animation to current location?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your camera to the first position of the user using this function:

```
yourGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, 8));
```

- position is a LatLng object containing your user latitude and longitude.
- 8 the desired zoom level, in the range of 2.0 to 21.0.